# can I put a SQL query on PHPMyadmin to implement automatically?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

In my website I have some value's field that must change depending on the change in another value's field, so i want them update automatically

**for example:** update the status of all students that haven't any courses by query:

```
UPDATE  `students`  
SET  `completed` = IF( `remainCourses` = 0  is true, 1, `completed`);
```

Maybe someone is wondering why I do not put them in the pages of the site within the php code? Because I need these values on several pages and should be updated, it's difficult to make a query in each page so i wonder if can I put a SQL query on PHPMyadmin to implement  automatically? which will make it easier

Comment: do you have connection to host? are you using windows or linux? is it on cPanel?

Comment: So you got an event on which you want to let an action an action happen? Sounds like your searching for [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Comment: I am not sure about his intention. I may misunderstand him, but SQL he shared put me on direction that he is looking for scheduling. anyway will se

Comment: @Simonare yes connected to host  which using cpanel and i'm using windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySql's Event Scheduler

You first need to configure it

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

then

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
  UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html)

---

you can also use commandline/shell to execute your script

```
mysql -h "server-name" -u "root" "-pXXXXXXXX" "database-name" < "filename.sql"
```

if you are on Windows, you can use TaskScheduler to schedule your script

if you are on Linux, you can use crontab to schedule your script

**Edit: OP reported that he is using cPanel**

You can schedule your jobs using cPanel, [Read this](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/74Docs/Cron+Jobs)

Comment: i don't know if this what i search but i need to read about the subject and then i will return to ask you, thank you